# Can't build apk with the last android studio when the sdk version is changed to 4.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a project that can run on android 4.4.
When pressing 'F4'  ( open module setting ), I see that the 'Compile sdk version is on API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

But my cellPhone is with version 4.4.2, so I move the version back as I define when I create the project => to  API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Now, nothing works ... the IDE can't find the 'R' anywhere ... and I can't compile it.

I try to clear and rebuild the project 
I try to click on the 'sync'

when i leave compile SDK at 23 and set your TARGET SDK to 19 .. the debug is not run on my cellphone.

but nothing .. not working.

Any help please ...

10x

Comment: do what phxhawke says, and then clean or rebuild project from Build menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your compile SDK at 23, set your TARGET SDK to 19.

Comment: did it ... and then the debug on my cellphone can't work